# filter array object with array value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am trying to filter an array object with array value, here the code:

```
const array1 = [{
            "packaging": "Box",
            "price": "100"
        }, {
            "packaging": "Pcs",
            "price": "15",
        }, {
            "packaging": "Item",
            "price": "2",
        }];

const b = ['Pcs','Item']
const found = array1.filter(el => {
    for(i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      return el.packaging !== b[i];
    }
});

console.log(found);
```

my expected output is array with object doesnt not exist in b
[{ packaging: "Box", price: "100" }]

Comment: Your nested for loop is unnecessary, `.filter` already loops over the elements. Do as the answers below say and just return the desired condition right away (using `.includes`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `.includes` check instead:

```js
const array1 = [{
            "packaging": "Box",
            "price": "100"
        }, {
            "packaging": "Pcs",
            "price": "15",
        }, {
            "packaging": "Item",
            "price": "2",
        }];

const b = ['Pcs','Item']
const found = array1.filter(el => !b.includes(el.packaging));
console.log(found);
```

Comment: That was a quick one using `includes` instead of `b.indexOf(item) == -1`. :) However, would you always suggest using includes ahead of old-fashioned way, in terms of performance? Or both are equal?

Comment: `.includes` might be a bit faster since it doesn't have to look at the index, just return a boolean - but what matters far more in real world situations is readability, 95% of the time, which `.includes` wins hands-down.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following,

```
const array1 = [{
            "packaging": "Box",
            "price": "100"
        }, {
            "packaging": "Pcs",
            "price": "15",
        }, {
            "packaging": "Item",
            "price": "2",
        }];

const b = ['Pcs','Item']
const found = array1.filter(el => {
    return b.findIndex(item => item === el.packaging) <= -1;
});

console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```js
const arr1 = [
  {"packaging": "Box", "price": "100"}, 
  {"packaging": "Pcs", "price": "15"}, 
  {"packaging": "Item", "price": "2"}
];

const arr2 = ['Pcs','Item'];
const found = arr1.filter(item => {
  return arr2.indexOf(item.packaging) === -1;
});

console.log(found);
```